# type mismatch vba error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to replace links on a spreadsheet using VBA and am getting a type mismatch error and can't figure out the reason.

Mycode:

```
    Dim aLinks as variant
    Dim myPath, name as String

aLinks = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
myPath = "C:\"
name = "test.xlsm"

    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=aLinks, NewName:=myPath & name, Type:=xlExcelLinks
```

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: myPath is declared as variant implicitly. it should be Dim myPath As String, name As String

Comment: No, its not, I just cut all in between to show only the parts I speak off. My path, aLinks and name are all stated previously

Comment: Fair enough. I just edited it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aLinks = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
```

The type of that would be a `Variant()` array.

```
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=aLinks, NewName:=myPath & name, Type:=xlExcelLinks
```

...and you can't coerce an array into a `String`.

You probably need to figure out *which item in that array* contains the name you want. For example:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=aLinks(1), NewName:=myPath & name, Type:=xlExcelLinks
```

Comment: There's only one name in the array, as there is only one link. I have tried the same code pasting the aLinks to a cell and it works fine. The change link code is the one going wrong

Comment: That still gives you a variant array - with one item in it.

Comment: And how to I specify the item?

Answer (score 1):

`aLinks` needs to be declared as a String or cast to a string `Cstr(aLinks)`.  Path should also be declared as a String but because you are concatenating it with a String, it will be cast into a String `myPath & name`.

[Workbook.ChangeLink Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-changelink-method-excel)

```
Name    Required    String  The name of the Microsoft Excel or DDE/OLE link to be changed, as it was returned from the LinkSources method.
NewName Required    String  The new name of the link.
Type    Optional    XlLinkType  The link type.
```